# Audiosystem stops writing AudioInputStream too early

Tags: java, audio, wav, java-io

Due to restrictions, i need to download a wav file on the first startup.

I have that file hosted on server `foo.bar/foo.wav`.

If i open a Connection to that url and pipe that into a clip, the audio plays fine.

Im doing this using:

```
public static AudioInputStream downloadSound(String link) {
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = urlConn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        AudioInputStream soundInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bis);
        // Starting the clip here also works perfectly
        return soundInput;
    } catch (IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now, when i want to safe the inputstream to a wav file using:

```
public void saveSound(AudioInputStream stream, String name) {
    this.createFolderIfNotExist("/sound");
    File soundfile = new File(mainPath + "/sound/" + name); 
    Clip clip;
    try {
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(stream);
        clip.start();
        // The Clip starts normally here. ( this block is just for testing purposes)
    } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        AudioSystem.write(stream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, soundfile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now my Problem is, that only a part of the audio, to be precise 1s, gets saved into the wav file.

I've already checked and i have the complete file on the server, i also have verified, piping the audioinputstream into a Clip and playing it plays the complete audio.

Now my question: How do i write the complete stream to a file or do i even have to do it this way and this there an simpler way to download that wav file to a specific location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i've found a workaround for my problem, now instead of getting the audioInputStream from the server im just handling the stream as a normal stream and write it using java io's Files.

```
public static void downloadSoundandSave(String url, String name) {
   Filesystem filesystem = new Filesystem();
    try (InputStream in = URI.create(url).toURL().openStream()) {
        filesystem.createFolderIfNotExist("/sound");
        Files.copy(in, Paths.get(filesystem.getMainPath() + "/sound/" + name));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```